# invite facebook friends to application without a popup rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook

I'm making a simple application to practice learning rails and web development in general.

What I'd like to do is list facebook friends so that I can invite those that don't have the app to come use it with me.

Currently I'm following a tutorial which pops up the friends on facebook I can send the application to. However I'd like to remove the popup option and simply display on the page the facebook friends invitation list (i.e. checkbox, name, picture). How would I go about doing that?

Here is my code of Home.html.erb. Please let me know if you have any suggestions. Thanks!

```
<div id="friends">

#instead of the below link which creates the pop up, I'd like the page to 
#simply display the facebook friends to invite

<p><%= link_to "Invite your Facebook Friends","#",:id=>"invite_fb_friends"%></p>

<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script src ="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
<script>
$(function(){
    $("a#invite_fb_friends").click(function(){
        FB.init({
            appId:'1234567890', #<--fake appid, my code includes the my actual app id
            cookie:false,
            status:true
        });

        FB.ui({method:'apprequests',message:'<%=current_user.name%> would like to invite you to try out our app!'});
    });
});
</script>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get a user's friends info (provided you have the permissions in the access token) via:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/:facebook_user_id/friends?access_token=token
```

You'll receive a json response of the user's friends. Simple parse the JSON code, and from their create a list of friends in the view. Use check boxes or something, compile each ID they select, and create a [request](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/concepts/requests/)

To see what the data looks like, goto: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer

and put in `/me/friends`

Comment: Hi @agmcleod Thank you for your answer. I reviewed it and used koala to obtain JSON code. However, do you have any suggestions on how to paginate that code? I used get_connections("me","friends") to obtain the JSON code. Is there an efficient way to display / paginate the information? Or should I use the FQL query for this?

Comment: With a string of the response body, use JSON.parse(str). You'll get a hash back of the data. If you want to look into how to paginate it in the UI, you'll need to make some sort of front-end widget, similar to how the dialogue you were using works. Personally, i would (and have) used the dialogue facebook gives, as it requires a lot less work. It also works on mobile.